# Checking File Path When Deleting A File

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

If I have a web method that deletes a file when called and it accepts three parameters (cNum, year, and fileName). Do I need to be worried about exploits of this method. The only thing I could think of would be using `..\..\..\` to drive the delete further up the folder structure. that should be pretty easy to remove that. But is there anything else that I should be worried about?

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true, 
           Description = "Method for deleting files uploaded by customers")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public Boolean deleteCustFiles(string cNum, string year, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cNum) 
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(year) 
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                throw new Exception();

        string path = Server.MapPath(@"~\docs\custFiles\" 
                                        + year + @"\" 
                                        + cNum + @"\" + fileName);
        File.Delete(path);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to delete file");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: not sure if wildcards can be used but that may be another problem...

Comment: Before you do File.Delete I would certainly check to make sure the file exists, that would allow you to provide a better message letting the user know the file does not exist instead of a general 'Unable to delete file' message.

Comment: you shouldnt throw `Exception`, or if you do, dont throw `Exception`, `FileNotFoundException` is better. or return false which is better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would recommend using the [`GetFileName` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) on the [`Path` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bdzys9w.aspx) to cleanse the filename parameter, like so:

```
public Boolean deleteCustFiles(string cNum, string year, string fileName)
{
    // Cleanse fileName.
    fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
```

The `GetFileName` method strips all directory information from a path, which is exactly what you want to do here.

With input like:

```
..\..\..\filename.ext
```

You would get:

```
filename.ext
```

In return, you don't have to worry about someone injecting a path which would escape the directory that you are targeting (assuming that this filename is user-input or from an open endpoint where someone could enter any input they want).

This then allows you to then append your custom path to `fileName`.

This only works of course if all of your files are in a pre-defined directory, which it seems it is.

This does *not* however, do anything to handle deleting files that a user doesn't have access to.  If the files belong to *another* user in that directory, then there's no check here to see if that's the case (but if *all* users have rights to delete these files, then it's ok).

Also, you might want to use the [`Combine` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) on the `Path` class to combine your paths, like so:

```
string path = Server.MapPath(@"~\docs\custFiles\")
path = Path.Combine(path, year);
path = Path.Combine(path, cNum);
path = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
```

If you're using .NET 4.0 or above, you can use [the overload of the `Combine` method that takes the parts of the path as a parameter array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142.aspx):

```
string path = Path.Combine(
    Server.MapPath(@"~\docs\custFiles\"),
    year, cNum, fileName);
```

Finally, as [Shai points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14145105/50776), if possible (for a complete solution), to make this even more secure you should be enabling permissions on the file-system level.

If you are impersonating the user or using a constrained user account to handle all of the requests, then you should grant that user access to just the  `~\docs\custFiles\` directory (and any sub directories).

Anything *above* that directory the user account should have *no* access to.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to check the file names and directory names if they are valid file names or not, check them against this char array:

[`Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx)

**EDIT:**

And you should probably also validate the year and number like this:

`bool valid = int.TryParse(num, out temp);`

Comment: Why try and validate the year and number?  This is only useful if the sub directories are *not* the only sub directories in the directory structure and those other sub directories are not user-accessible.  I wouldn't expect this to be the case since I'd expect `custFiles` to be completely driven by users and not by code.  Any information about files/directories in there should be stored somewhere else completely.

Comment: @casperOne , From what the question has, it appears that he needs to validate the year and number using `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` , which suggested that maybe it depends on user input, and that he is not sure of the variables value, so extra validation could be useful in making sure that those variables have exactly what is expected for them to have.

Comment: "Could be useful" - You're not showing where it could be useful.  Let's say that there are two directories, 1998 and 1999.  If the user input is "abcd" then the directory doesn't exist and nothing is deleted.  If someone legitimately sends "1988", then there's no problem, the file is deleted.  However, if someone sends "1999" maliciously (let's say the file is in both) to delete something that one thought should be in 1998, parsing the integer has no effect here; it didn't keep the user from accessing a directory they shouldn't have.  It doesn't add any extra security.

Comment: @casperOne , Isn't it possible to have `..` in one of those variables ?

Comment: Yes, in which case, parsing for an integer *might* help, but you might want to use `Path.GetFileName` instead and just strip it completely.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider using built in security on the file system to prevent users from deleting files in unwanted directories. If the web app is running under a specific user that  has rights to delete files in only one directory, no matter what the user tries, the app will  not have the rights to perform the delete.

In addition, this would make maintenance (ie: adding new directories) pretty easy without redeploying the app.

You could then catch the attempt to access the invalid access attempt and do something with it if you so desire.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true, 
    Description = "Method for deleting files uploaded by customers")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public Boolean deleteCustFiles(string cNum, string year, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cNum) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(year) ||
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            throw new Exception();
        string path = 
            Server.MapPath(@"~\docs\custFiles\" + year + @"\" + cNum + 
                @"\" + fileName);
        File.Delete(path);
    }
    catch (System.Security.SecurityException e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unauthorized attempt to delete file");
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to delete file");
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: While built in security for the file system is a good addition, you're possibly propagating the attack from the input.  Attention should *still* be paid to the input that's coming in from the user if there's a certain expectation about it.  In this case, there absolutely is one, that directory information *won't* be there.

Comment: @casperOne: I don't understand what you mean by _possibly propagating the attack_. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Take for example if `..\..\filename.ext` was passed in.  Granted, you shouldn't give permissions to anything two directories up to the user that is actually performing the delete, but that's not a complete solution.  You should *always* sanitize the inputs.